# Kotlin channel not ready to send events after put app in background

Tags: android, kotlin, channel, kotlin-coroutines

Kotlin channel stops being able to send events after putting app in background (don't keep activities enabled)

```
class UserRepositoryImpl(
    private val userRequestDataSource: UserRequestDataSourceContract,
) : UserRepositoryContract {

private var loginToken: LoginTokenDecode? = null
private val authChannel by lazy { Channel<Boolean?>() }

override suspend fun requestLogin(userLoginBo: UserLoginRequestBo){
   // isClosedForSend is true after putting app in background
   if(!authChannel.isClosedForSend)  {
     authChannel.send(true)
   }
}
```

Viewmodel

```
class UserViewModel : ViewModel {
  init {
     authChannelUc.invoke(scope = viewModelScope, onResult = ::authenticated)
  }
 ...
}
```

Comment: What's the scope or lifespan of the User Repository contract?

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous viewmodel scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the consumer side, use *for*:

```
 for (token in authChannel) {
      withContext(dispatcherForLaunch) {
         onResult(isTokenValid(loginTokenDecode))
      }
 }
```

instead `authChannel.consumerEach())`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that you are using `viewModelScope`; and the fact that you have "Do not keep activities in background" enabled on device - The Activity is killed going to background, which cancels the `viewModelScope`, which auto-closes the channel.

Comment: But when I came to the app, viewmodel is recreated and sends again the viewmodel scope

Comment: View Models are retained only for device rotation, not for activity restarts in cases like yours. For your use-case I think you need a background service, which is not in viewModelScope.

Comment: Is happening also to me and I’m rotating the device…